# Attempting to bring gravity into a Mario like platform game in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am working on creating a donkey kong like game in which I will have Mario try to reach the top platform. To do this, I need Mario to have the ability to jump and fall with gravity.

I have been working on implementing gravity, but when I tried something that I thought would work, the gravity element worked, but the player avatar began to glitch erratically. I believe this is because he is moving up and down several times per second. Any help as to how resolve this issue, and get my gravity mechanism functioning would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

````
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools

global moves

pygame.init()
screen_height = 800
screen_width = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Donkey Kong')

FPS = 30

player = pygame.image.load('mario.bmp') #facing right
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_rect.center = (80, 700)

move_rate = 3
move_left = False
move_right = False
move_up = False
move_down = False

touch_ladder = True
ladder_move_up = False
ladder_move_down = False

gravity = 4
gravity_check = True

jump = False
jump_moves = 0

platform = pygame.image.load('platform.bmp')
platforms = []
platform_x = [60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480]

platform_y = [120,240,360,480,600,720]

ladders = []
ladder_x = [300, 480, 240, 300, 180, 420, 240, 120, 60, 420, 300, 480]
ladder_y = []

class Platform():

    def __init__(self, y, x, x_index, y_index):
        self.platform = platform
        self.rect = self.platform.get_rect()
        self.x_index = x_index
        self.y_index = y_index
        if (self.y_index % 2) != 0 :
            self.rect.y = y + (2 * self.x_index)
        else:
            self.rect.y = y - (2 * self.x_index)
        self.rect.x = x  

    def draw_platform(self):
        if (self.rect.y % 240) != 0:
            screen.blit(self.platform, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y )) #up
        else:
            screen.blit(self.platform, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)) #down


class Ladder():

    def __init__(self, y, x, y_index, x_index):
        self.y_index = y_index
        self.x_index = x_index
        if (y % 240) != 0:
            self.height = abs(((platform_y[self.y_index - 1] + (2 *(2 * self.x_index)))) - y)
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y - self.height, 20, self.height)
            self.rect.y -= (2 * self.x_index)
        else:
            self.height = abs(((platform_y[self.y_index - 1] - (2 * (2 * self.x_index)))) - y)
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y - self.height, 20, self.height)
            self.rect.y += (2 * self.x_index)
        self.rungs = 0

    def draw_ladder(self):
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y , 4, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.rect.x + 16, self.rect.y, 4, self.height))

    def draw_rungs(self):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y+self.rungs),(self.rect.x + 19, self.rect.y+self.rungs), 4)
        self.rungs += 14

y_multiplied = platform_y.copy()
y_multiplied.extend(platform_y)
y_multiplied.sort()
print(y_multiplied)
print(ladder_x)

for y in platform_y:
    if platform_y.index(y) < 6:
        for x in platform_x:
            platforms.append(Platform(y, x, platform_x.index(x), platform_y.index(y)))

for y, x in zip(y_multiplied, ladder_x):
    ladders.append(Ladder(y, x, platform_y.index(y), platform_x.index(x)))


while True:
    gravity_check = True

    screen.fill((105, 105, 255))
    screen.blit(player, player_rect)


    for p in platforms:
        p.draw_platform()
        if player_rect.colliderect(p.rect):
            player_rect.bottom = p.rect.top
            gravity_check = False

    for l in ladders:
        if player_rect.colliderect(l.rect):
            touch_ladder = True
            gravity_check = False

    if gravity_check == True:
        player_rect.y += gravity

    for l in ladders:
        if l.y_index > 0:
            l.draw_ladder()
            for i in range(l.height // 14):
                l.draw_rungs()
            l.rungs = 0


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                player = pygame.transform.flip(player, True, False)
                move_left = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
                player = pygame.image.load('mario.bmp')
            if event.key == K_UP:
                jump = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += move_rate

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False

    if move_left == True:
        player_rect.x -= move_rate
    if move_right == True:
        player_rect.x += move_rate

    if ladder_move_up == True:
        player_rect.y -= move_rate

    if jump == True:
        gravity_check = True
        if jump_moves <= 60:
            player_rect.y -= 10
            jump_moves += 10
        else:
            jump_moves = 0
            jump = False


    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)```
````

Comment: I am currently looking your code, hope I'll be able to help. But I am interested why are you loading the image again in loop `player = pygame.image.load('mario.bmp')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line causes problems:

```
if gravity_check == True:
        player_rect.y += gravity
```

If you put `print()`:

```
if gravity_check == True:
        print(player_rect.y)
        player_rect.y += gravity
        print(player_rect.y)
```

You'll see that `player_rect.y` constantly changes between `56 and 60` (for my random image) at the start. So you need to prevent change of the `player_rect.y` on more than one place simultaneously to avoid this behaviour. Also as I mentioned in the comment try to avoid loading images inside of the loop because it will consume much resources.

EDIT:

```
 for p in platforms:
        p.draw_platform()
        if player_rect.colliderect(p.rect):
            player_rect.bottom = p.rect.top + gravity
            gravity_check = False
```

`player_rect.bottom = p.rect.top + gravity` adding `gravity` value will solve the problem. And this is the line of code that was causing changes to `player_rect.y` as well as one mentioned in the original post. Hope this solves your problem.